# Spring form checkboxes - matching by toString() thus checking off wrong checkboxes

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, checkbox

I have a domain object **ContactGroup** which holds a ManyToMany reference to another domain object, **Person**:

```
@Entity
public class ContactGroup {

@ManyToMany
private Set<Person> members = new HashSet<>();

  [...]
}
```

I need to edit a **ContactGroup** and show a) *all* possible **Persons** with form:checkboxes and b) selet those, already contained within **members**

It works nicely so far. I'm using the form:checkboxes tag to bind to **members** and contain a model attribute **personList** as items:

```
 <form:checkboxes path="members" multiple="true" items="${personList}" itemLabel="displayString" itemValue="id"/>
```

---

***So what is the problem?***

Apparently, spring compares the toString() of different items to evaluate if they should be checked or not. If two **Persons** have the same toString() representation, they will be both checked if one of them is checked.

How can I alter that behaviour? I tried adding custom binders, but that didn't change anything:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Person.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            setValue(personService.get(Long.parseLong(text)));
        }

    });

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "members", new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {
        @Override
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof Long) {
                return personService.get((Long) element);
            } else if (element instanceof String) {
                personService.get(Long.parseLong((String) element));
            } else if (element instanceof Person) {
                return element;
            }
            return null;
        }

    });
}
```